# Vimperator searching / hinting diacritics issue

Tags: firefox-extensions, vimperator

I wanna ask if is there any way to search/hint in vimperator without diacritics sensitivity. E.g. search for 'skola' and match 'škola'. It's really annyoing to constantly switch between english/czech keyboard.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reach that is with regular expressions (i think). This might help you.

http://wiki.vimperator-labs.googlecode.com/hg/VimperatorFAQ.wiki :

> == Can I use regular expressions to search? == As per `:help pattern.html`, Firefox does not provide native regular expression
>   support for searching, so Vimperator will probably never do this
>   natively. That being said, there is an extension to add it that meshes
>   well with Vimperator. Here are the steps to enable regular expression
>   searching:
>
> 1. Install the /Find Bar/ extension from    http://www.oxymoronical.com/web/firefox/FindBarRX
> 2. Restart Firefox.
> 3. Get the regular find bar. On the Mac this is Apple-f, other places     iCtrl-f (the `i` means "pass next key through to Firefox").
> 4. Check the regular expression box, and close the find bar.
> 5. The setting will stick, so that searching with / will use regular expressions. Don't forget to escape characters like '/' and '.'.
>
> NB: The {{{/Find Bar/}}} extension is no longer actively developed.
>   There has been at least one case of it causing Firefox to crash on
>   startup. ''Caveat emptor''.